# sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file (Disaster Response Pipelines)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

My python code for Data Science about Disaster Response Pipelines shows an error, and I don't know the reason for it.

I execute:

```
python app/runn.py ../models/classifier.pkl  sqlite:///../data/DisasterResponse.db
```

and get this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
import json
import plotly
import pandas as pd
import pickle

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


app = Flask(__name__)

def tokenize(text):
    '''
    INPUT 
        text: Text to be processed   
    OUTPUT
        Returns a processed text variable that was tokenized, lower cased, stripped, and lemmatized
    '''
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    clean_tokens = []
    for tok in tokens:
        clean_tok = lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok).lower().strip()
        clean_tokens.append(clean_tok)

    return clean_tokens

# load data
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///../data/DisasterResponse.db')
df =  pd.read_sql_table('DisasterMessage', engine)

print(df.head())

# load model
model = pickle.load(open("../models/classifier.pkl", 'rb'))
print(model)

X = df.message.values
y = df.iloc[:,5:]

keys = list(y.columns)
my_dict = {key: None for key in keys}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[key] = ((y[key] == 1)).sum()

# index webpage displays cool visuals and receives user input text for model
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():

    # extract data needed for visuals
    genre_counts = df.groupby('genre').count()['message']
    genre_names = list(genre_counts.index)

    ### data for visualizing category counts.
    label_sums = df.iloc[:, 4:].sum()
    label_names = list(label_sums.index)

    # create visuals
    graphs = [
        {
            'data': [
                Bar(
                    x=genre_names,
                    y=genre_counts
                )
            ],

            'layout': {
                'title': 'Distribution of Message Genres',
                'yaxis': {
                    'title': "Count"
                },
                'xaxis': {
                    'title': "Genre"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'data': [
                Bar(
                    x=label_names,
                    y=label_sums,
                )
            ],

            'layout': {
                'title': 'Distribution of categories',
                'yaxis': {
                    'title': "Count"
                },
                'xaxis': {

                },
            }
        }

]

    # encode plotly graphs in JSON
    ids = ["graph-{}".format(i) for i, _ in enumerate(graphs)]
    graphJSON = json.dumps(graphs, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    # render web page with plotly graphs
    return render_template('master.html', ids=ids, graphJSON=graphJSON)

# web page that handles user query and displays model results
@app.route('/go')
def go():
    # save user input in query
    query = request.args.get('query', '') 

    # use model to predict classification for query
    classification_labels = model.predict([query])[0]
    classification_results = dict(zip(df.columns[4:], classification_labels))

    # This will render the go.html Please see that file. 
    return render_template(
        'go.html',
        query=query,
        classification_result=classification_results
    )

def main():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3001, debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2228, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 365, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 822, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 554, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1346, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 370, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 499, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 701, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 437, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/runn.py", line 37, in <module>
    df =  pd.read_sql_table('DisasterMessage', engine)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 240, in read_sql_table
    meta.reflect(only=[table_name], views=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4097, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2171, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 103, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2259, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2232, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1528, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 296, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 276, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2228, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 365, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 822, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 554, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1346, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 370, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 499, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 701, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 437, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: "unable to open database file" is the reason in the error. Check the file is in the right plce.